# JSON and scope. Using a closure

Tags: javascript, json, scope

I am trying to understand why the variable index is being updated ( added and subtracted ) when my function returns an object.

```
var init = (function() {
    var index = 0;
    return function() {

            return {

                    subtract: index -= 1,
                    add: index = index + 1,
                    getIndex: index

            }

    }
})();

console.log(init().getIndex);  // 1
console.log(init().add); // 2
console.log(init().getIndex);  //2
```

Instead 0 is returned. This is because when the object is returned all of the properties in that returned object are execute. SO my question is how do i prevent that from happening.

Comment: i want the number 2 to be returned. when i execute those three lines of console.log(...)

Comment: `subtract`, `add`, and `getIndex` should be functions. If you want to understand how it works, read about "closures".

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it returns 0. It should return undefined:

```
var f = init();

// f is now the returned function. Therefore:

f.getIndex; // should be undefined
f().getIndex; // should be 1
```

Therefore, the to get the expected output, change your code to:

```
console.log(init()().getIndex);  // 1
console.log(init()().add); // 2
console.log(init()().getIndex);  //2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var init = (function() {
    var index = 0;
    return function() {
        return {
            subtract: function() { return --index; },
            add:      function() { return ++index; },
            getIndex: function() { return index; }
        }
    }
})();

console.log(init().getIndex());  // 0
console.log(init().add()); // 1
console.log(init().getIndex());  // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

subtract, add and getIndex aren't being initiated as functions. They are receiving the values -1, 0 and 0.

To return operations set

```
var init = (function() {
    var index = 0;

    return {
        subtract: function () { index -= 1 },
        add: function () { index + 1 }, // Should probably be += here
        getIndex: function () { return index; }
    }
}();
```